# Python 3.4.3 - Windows 8.1 64bit - Error on "pip install codeintel"

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, sublimecodeintel

I am trying to install codeintel for python so my sublime text 3 will work with code intel when writing Python code.  I am on Windows 8.1 64bit and my Python version is 3.4.3

When i run:

```
pip install codeintel
```

I get the following error

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
```

I have seen some similar questions on here but can't really see a good resolution.  Anyone been able to get this to work properly?

edit:

Forget to mention that I have Visual Studio Community 2013 installed with nothing missing that I know of.  I have regularly built Visual C++ programs for a class I am taking so I know it is on there somewhere.

Comment: Well, do you have [Visual C++ 2010](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) installed? Try installing that.

Comment: my bad, forget to mention that I have Visual Studio Community 2013 installed with nothing missing that I know of.  I have regularly built Visual C++ programs for another class, so It is definitely on my computer.

Comment: You need version 2010 specifically. In order to build Python C extensions, you need to use the version of Visual Studio used to build Python itself, and that means [VS 2010 for Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install `codeintel` to get autocompletion/code intelligence in Sublime Text 3. While the next version of [`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) (SCI) will require it, I strongly suggest using the (in my opinion) superior [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) package, which despite its name has nothing to do with the Anaconda Python release. In my experience, it's much faster and more accurate than SCI, easier to set up out of the box, and just generally works better.